# Porque estos patrones de identificación con grupos de captura no consiguen identificar estas secuencias de texto para reemplazarles?

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, regex, str-replace

```py
import re

#ejemplo reducido
input_text = "((CONTEXT) de María Rosa) cosas viejas de aqui, ya que"

#ejemplo completo:
input_text = "((PERSON)María Rosa) ((VERB)pasará) unos dias aqui, hay que ((VERB)mover) ((CONTEXT) de María Rosa) cosas viejas de aqui, ya que ((CONTEXT) de María Rosa) cosméticos ((VERB)estorban) si ((VERB)estan) tirados por aquí. ((PERSON)Cyntia) es una buena modelo, ((CONTEXT) de Cyntia) cabello ((VERB)es) muy bello, hay que ((VERB)lavar) ((CONTEXT) de Cyntia) cabello"

action_context_capture_pattern  = r"\(\(CONTEXT\)((?:\w\s*))+\)"
associated_info_capture_pattern = r"((?:\w\s*)+)((?:\s+(?:del|de )|\s*(?:\(\(VERB\)|[.,;]|$)))"

#Convinando estos patrones queda:  r"\(\(CONTEXT\)((?:\w\s*))+\)\s*((?:\w\s*)+)((?:\s+(?:del|de )|\s*(?:\(\(VERB\)|[.,;]|$)))"
input_text = re.sub(action_context_capture_pattern + r"\s*" + associated_info_capture_pattern, 
                    lambda m: (f"((CONTEXT){m[2]} {m[1]}){m[3]}"),
                    input_text, flags = re.IGNORECASE)

print(repr(input_text)) # --> output
```

¿Por qué la identificación del patrón de las subcadenas a reemplazar no identifica coincidencias en la cadena? Y en consecuencia tampoco hace los reemplazos con `re.sub()`. Es bastante extraño porque no detecta absolutamente ninguna de las ocurrencias.

Estos serian los outputs correctos:

```
#output correcto del ejemplo reducido
"((CONTEXT)cosas viejas de María Rosa) de aqui, ya que"

#output correcto del ejemplo completo
'((PERSON)María Rosa) ((VERB)pasará) unos dias aqui, hay que ((VERB)mover) ((CONTEXT)cosas viejas de María Rosa) de aqui, ya que ((CONTEXT)cosméticos de María Rosa) ((VERB)estorban) si ((VERB)estan) tirados por aquí. ((PERSON)Cyntia) es una buena modelo, ((CONTEXT)cabello de Cyntia) ((VERB)es) muy bello, hay que ((VERB)lavar) ((CONTEXT)cabello de Cyntia)'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El problema aquí es que los patrones de captura que estás usando para identificar las subcadenas a reemplazar no están capturando correctamente las subcadenas que deseas.

El patrón `action_context_capture_pattern` selecciona correctamente la cadena `"((CONTEXT) de María Rosa)"`, pero el patrón `associated_info_capture_pattern` no está capturando la información asociada correctamente. Este patrón solo captura palabras consecutivas seguidas de un espacio o un punto final.

Para solucionar este problema, modifica el patrón `associated_info_capture_pattern` para que capture todas las palabras consecutivas, independientemente de si están seguidas de un espacio o no:

```
associated_info_capture_pattern = r"((?:\w+\s*)+)((?:\s+(?:del|de )|\s*(?:\(\(VERB\)|[.,;]|$)))"
```

Además, en la función `re.sub` en la que estás haciendo el reemplazo, debes intercambiar los índices de las grupos de captura en el argumento `lambda`, para que capture la información asociada antes de la cadena `"((CONTEXT))"`:

```
input_text = re.sub(action_context_capture_pattern + r"\s*" + associated_info_capture_pattern, 
                    lambda m: (f"((CONTEXT){m[1]} {m[2]}){m[3]}"),
                    input_text, flags = re.IGNORECASE)
```

Con estos cambios, deberías obtener los outputs correctos que has especificado. Saludos!

**Editado:**

El error `"unbalanced parenthesis"` significa que hay un número impar de paréntesis en la expresión regular, lo que indica un error de sintaxis en la expresión regular. Por ejemplo, si hay un paréntesis de apertura que no tiene un paréntesis de cierre correspondiente, o viceversa. En este caso, debes revisar la expresión regular y asegurarte de que todos los paréntesis estén equilibrados.

```
import re

input_text = "((PERSON)María Rosa) ((VERB)pasará) unos dias aqui, hay que ((VERB)mover) ((CONTEXT) de María Rosa) cosas viejas de aqui, ya que ((CONTEXT) de María Rosa) cosméticos ((VERB)estorban) si ((VERB)estan) tirados por aquí. ((PERSON)Cyntia) es una buena modelo, ((CONTEXT) de Cyntia) cabello ((VERB)es) muy bello, hay que ((VERB)lavar) ((CONTEXT) de Cyntia) cabello"

action_context_capture_pattern  = r"\(\(CONTEXT\)((?:\w\s*))+\)"
associated_info_capture_pattern = r"((?:\w\s*)+)((?:\s+(?:del|de )|\s*(?:\(\(VERB\)|[.,;]|$)))"

#Convinando estos patrones queda:  r"\(\(CONTEXT\)((?:\w\s*))+\)\s*((?:\w\s*)+)((?:\s+(?:del|de )|\s*(?:\(\(VERB\)|[.,;]|$)))"
input_text = re.sub(action_context_capture_pattern + r"\s*" + associated_info_capture_pattern, 
                    lambda m: (f"((CONTEXT){m[2]} {m[1]}){m[3]}"),
                    input_text, flags = re.IGNORECASE)

print(repr(input_text))
```

Comment: He modificado esas 2 cosas pero sigue sin capturar nada. Checa el code aqui: https://www.online-python.com/COhcTmD78f

Comment: Editado, revisa la respuesta

Comment: He intentado aun con eso, pero a mi no me da ningun error, tan solo no realiza las identificaciones y el re.sub() no hace nada. https://www.online-python.com/15H03tuGRW

Comment: Una observación en el ejemplo ((CONTEXT) de ..) hay un espacio que la expresión regular no contempla, considerando que \w no captura espacio.

Comment: El ```action_context... ``` no captura ```((CONTEXT) de María Rosa)``` por el espacio entre ) y de

Comment: Lo correcto para action__ es:  ```r"\(\(CONTEXT\)\s*((?:\w\s*)+)\)```

Comment: @JuanCarlosGuibovich Tienes razon ese era el fallo que tenia, muchas gracias. Quedando el reemplazo asi:  `input_text = re.sub(action_context_capture_pattern + r"\s*" + associated_info_capture_pattern, lambda m: (f"((CONTEXT){m[2]} {m[1]}){m[3]}").replace("  ", " "), input_text, flags = re.IGNORECASE)`

Comment: La respuesta que diste como solución debe ser editada y modificada para que refleje una soluci9n verdqdera